# Monerod - inital sync running for 7 days with 27% to go. Is this normal?

Tags: monerod, synchronization

Running an initial node sync with Monerod on Windows 11 for testing purposes. Very log disk and CPU usage all the way through. Now 7 days into the download. The process is continuing to slow with 27% to go.

What is a reasonable length of time for an initial download sync?
Is the time taken dependent on the length of time taken to verify the hash on each block? Obviously I mean verify and not discover.
Should I use the block sync size parameter? Something like: E.G --block-sync-size 4 --db-sync-mode fastest:sync:8750

./monerod --no-zmq --out-peers 64 --in-peers 32 --add-priority-node=p2pmd.xmrvsbeast.com:18080 --add-priority-node=nodes.hashvault.pro:18080 --disable-dns-checkpoints --enable-dns-blocklist --data-dir 'E:\xxxxx\MONERO'

2023-10-03 14:06:32.506 I Synced 2193172/2987790 (73%, 794618 left)
2023-10-03 14:07:26.365 I Synced 2193192/2987790 (73%, 794598 left, 20% of total synced, estimated 19.1 days left)
2023-10-03 14:08:57.386 I Synced 2193212/2987791 (73%, 794579 left)
2023-10-03 14:10:51.393 I Synced 2193232/2987794 (73%, 794562 left, 20% of total synced, estimated 19.1 days left)
2023-10-03 14:12:04.970 I Synced 2193252/2987794 (73%, 794542 left)
2023-10-03 14:13:53.537 I Synced 2193272/2987795 (73%, 794523 left, 20% of total synced, estimated 19.1 days left)

Comment: Install SSD drives. Spinning HD drives are not suitable for blockchain data.

Comment: This is inaccurate. If you're planning on keeping your node connected and synced, and willing to have a slow *initial* sync, using a HDD is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With *default* settings and using an internally attached SSD,
   synchronization typically takes less that 12 hours, though this
   obviously varies based on your internet bandwidth and machine spec.
2. If you're using a spinning HD or an external (e.g. USB attached)
   disk for the blockchain, it's going to take *a lot* longer.
3. When you are past the last available checkpoint and as there are
   more transactions to verify, synchronization slows down.

Comment: I see. So machines with HDD drives are not suitable for running a node. Question resolved.

Comment: How do I mark a question resolved?

Comment: "So machines with HDD drives are not suitable for running a node" <- this is inaccurate. If you're planning on keeping your node connected and synced, and willing to have a slow *initial* sync, using a HDD is fine.